# How much time do I get when didUpdateToLocation fires in background app

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

I want to push the fix (blindly) to a server on the internet (simple socket send of about 100 bytes).  Will the iOS SDK give me enough time to do that when didUpdateToLocation starts me up in the background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that these location type services are allowed to run in the background (provided they identify themselves as such in the plist) without restriction. If you are concerned, wrap your processing in a - (UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier)beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:(void(^)(void))handler
 function, which I think gives you about 10 minutes of processing, which should be plenty of time.